# How to write an "If(And" code with unknown number of cells in column?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to check if all cells in a column are less than 1? If there were only a few cells, with the number of cells known up front, I would use the code below.

However, from case to case the number of cells in column A will vary. I need to know if any of the cells in column A is less than 1.

If there is one (or more) cell containing a value less than 1, I need a cell (A1 for example) to show NOT OK. If only ALL the cells' values are greater than 1, I need the cell (A1 for example) to show OK.

If all cells in column A have values greater than 1, I want to continue and check column B for the same thing. Otherwise I want to save and close the workbook and continue with next open workbook...also with vba code.

Any suggestions on how to write this in VBA? Maybe there is way other than `If(AND...)`?

```
Sub IfAnd()

IF(AND(A5>1,A4>1,A3>1,A2>1),"OK", "NOT OK") 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will solve all your columns and insert the data in THE FIRST ROW OF EACH COLUMN

```
Sub Problems()

Dim CurCol, LastRow, LastCol as Long

LastCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For CurCol = 1 to LastCol
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, CurCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(2, CurCol), Cells(LastRow, CurCol))) < 1 Then
        Cells(1, CurCol).Value = "NOT OK"
    Else
        Cells(1, CurCol).Value = "OK"
    End If
Next CurCol

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant xlToLeft in lieu of xlLeft .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it without any worksheet functions.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ce As Range
Dim sr, lr, lc As Integer
'worksheet you are working with
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'column you are searching
Set ce = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1)
'start row set to 2 so row 1 will contain output
Let sr = 2
'search only the last row
Let lr = ce.End(xlUp).Row
Let lc = ws.Cells(sr, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For c = 1 To lc
For r = sr To lr
If ws.Cells(r, c).Value < 1 Then
ws.Cells(1, c).Value = "NOT OK"
GoTo NotOK
End If
Next r
ws.Cells(1, c).Value = "OK"
NotOK:
Set ce = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, c+1)
Let lr = ce.End(xlUp).Row
Next c
End Sub
```

This should be faster and more efficient for large data sets. Especially if it is sorted smallest to largest.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
=IF(MAX(A:A)<1)
```

Comment: Would that not require that ALL of the values be less than 1?

Comment: Is this the complete code?? Anyway this got me thinking!

Answer (score 0):

If VBA is not required, here is a worksheet formula that should do the job, and will also ignore blanks and non-numeric entries:

This formula must be **array-entered**:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER($A:$A),$A:$A)<1,0)),"NOT OK","OK")
```

If this formula must be located in A1, change the range references from $A:$A to $A$2:$A$1000 where 1000 represents the highest conceivable row number for the data.

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**< ctrl-shift >** while hitting **< enter >**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **{...}** around the formula.